# How to get included model data count in prisma with where clause?

Tags: count, prisma

> i need to get user details with post count(Number of posts for today).

```
const usersWithCount = await prisma.user.findMany({
      select: {
        _count: {
          select: {
            posts: {
             where: {
                       createdAt: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
                    },
                  },
            recipes: true,
          },
        },
      },
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot filter in relations count, this is not currently supported by prisma.
Here is the [Feature Request](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/8413) for adding filters in relations count.
In your use case you can get filtered relations as described below:

```js
  const usersWithCount = await prisma.user.findMany({
    select: {
      posts: {
        where: {
          createdAt: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
        },
      },
      recipes: true
    },
  });
```

In the response of the above query you will get posts array with records satisfying your where condition, you can use the array's length as a count.